# Refactof resharper LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

Мне решарпер подсказывает, что можно использовать метод Any()

```cs
if (methodInfo.CustomAttributes
    .Where(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(ApiMethodAttribute))
    .Select(x => x)
    .Count() == 0)
```

Как мне использовать подсказку решарпера? Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: `.Count() == 0` заменить на `.Any()`

Comment: Точно, спасибо большое!

Comment: на самом деле Select тут вообще лишний, а вместо Where можно сразу Any написать

Comment: А решарпер разве не предлагает свой вариант замены кода прямо в готовом виде?

Comment: Да, я и спрашиваю как применить этот готовый вариант. В рефакторе найти не смог его :(
@CrazyElf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `.Count() == 0` - меняется на `.Any()`, с добавлением отрицания перед всем условием, так как нужно проверить, что ничего нет, а не что-то есть
2. `Select` - никак не влияет на количество элементов, следовательно его можно убрать
3. у [`.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-any-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-boolean)))) есть специальная перегрузка принимающая предикат

таким образом исходный код может стать таким:

```
if (!methodInfo.CustomAttributes
    .Any(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(ApiMethodAttribute)))
```